# Как правильно поместить строку поиска в центр div

Tags: css, html5

Как правильно сверстать строку поиска, чтобы она была по центру `div`?
Есть вот такой `div` у меня с картинкой фоном.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно это поисковое поле поместить в центр.

```css
div {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.cover{
    background: url(../img/cover.jpg) no-repeat center top / cover;
    margin-top: 24px;
}

.search{
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<section>
        <div class="container">
            <img src="img/cover.jpg" alt="Cover" class="cover">
            <input type="text" name="" class = "search">
        </div>
 </section>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неправильно используете `text-align:center`,его надо задать для селектора `.container`.И сделайте `input` блочно-строчным, `display: inline-block;`